# Is “the tough get going” grammatically wrong?

Tags: grammar, idioms

I see an idiom: “when the going gets tough, the tough get going.”

Is there a reason why **get** in “the tough get going” doesn’t have ***s***?

Comment: **get going** =  spring into action, rise to the challenge.

Answer (score 4):

You know that sometimes `The + adjective` makes a plural noun and points to a group of people or things.

Since tough is an adjective, I think the reason is that `the + tough` is plural (it means **people who are strong**).

We have other examples like `The + poor` which means a group of poor people or `The rich` which means a group of rich people.

Comment: So the tough means tough people. I got it. I thought it meant “your toughness”.

Comment: @user67265 - _When the going gets tough, your toughness gets going_ would indeed be grammatical, albeit without the quaint parallelism of the usual idiom.

Comment: @user67265 yes it means tough, strong and enduring people. You can find the complete meaning of this phrase [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_the_going_gets_tough,_the_tough_get_going).